# Reg how to send the RTP packets through the proxy server

Tags: c++, symbian, rtp, pjsip

I am using the pjproject1.6 and I could send the sip packets through the sip packets to the proxy server and the rtp packets or not pass through the server. Hence the voice could not be heard on both sides.

I have checked in proxy server, rtp proxy is running and when proxy server sends 200 Ok, the SDP packets from PJSIP includes the IP address of the proxy server.

Still the sound/media are not transmitted to both PJMedia client and reciever.
I have tested the same scenario with the yate client, audio/media is heard both on the sender and reciever.

Is there any other config/code change that should taken care from PJSIP?

Comment: Can you tell use which software package is running the SIP proxy? And what's running the RTP proxy? How did you determine RTP packets were not travelling to the proxy? Just because you're not hearing audio on the other end, or did you use a packet sniffer? There are many reasons why Yate may work while PJSIP doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find the below log trace for the packets that are transmitted/recived from the server

Packet sent to server

INVITE sip:yyyyy@x.x.x.x:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.122.15.112:2370;branch=z9hG4bK8b9359940aa1224a09cd8cfa27959d48;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: ;tag=a604814d1290cc805caf160bdccb9390^M
To: 
Call-ID: 1002437405@x.x.x.x-b2b_1
CSeq: 201 INVITE
Contact: Anonymous 
Expires: 300
User-Agent: Sippy B2BUA (RADIUS)
cisco-GUID: 1368145855-893785068-3325200664-2859798416
h323-conf-id: 1368145855-893785068-3325200664-2859798416
Content-Length: 383
Content-Type: application/sdp

v=0
o=- 1290749418547 1290749418547 IN IP4 10.122.15.112
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 10.122.15.112
t=0 0
m=audio 33564 RTP/AVP 8 11 98 98 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:11 L16/8000
a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:98 mode=20
a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:98 mode=30
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=ptime:30
a=nortpproxy:yes

Packet from x.x.x.x:5060

SIP/2.0 200 OK
CSeq: 201 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.122.15.112:2370;branch=z9hG4bK8b9359940aa1224a09cd8cfa27959d48;rport
From: ;tag=a604814d1290cc805caf160bdccb9390
Call-ID: 1002437405@213.146.168.52-b2b_1
To: ;tag=2711361009342964732656241
Contact: 
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 250

v=0
o=VoipSwitch 7240 7240 IN IP4 x.x.x.x
s=VoipSIP
i=Audio Session
c=IN IP4 x.x.x.x
t=0 0
m=audio 6240 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv

Comment: We had a proxy server setup with B2BUA-Sippy as SIP server and RTPProxy as rtp server. Audio is heard in the receiver end but no audio is heard in the orginator part . RTP packet trace is Shown above.